# Replace all elements of Numpy array greater than threshold with average of X adjacent values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, conditional-statements

I have this Numpy array that contains a data set

> array = np.array([3147, 3228, 3351, 3789, 4562, 4987, 5688, 6465, 7012, 7560, 
>   7976, 8615, 8698, 8853, 8783, 8949, 9066, 9123, 9172, 9411, 9717, 9696, 
>   9848,10113, 10154, 10227, 10439, 10672, 10287, 10386, 10417, 10585, 10607,10461, 
>   10654, 10739, 10634, 10490, 10544, 10645, 10392, 10330, 10044, 9560, 8711, 8152,
>    7506, 7191, 6994, 6601, 6609, 6670, 7293, **32767**, 7264, 7262, 7503 ,7872, 7826, 8037])

When plotted, it gives a smooth distribution but spikes with the outlier value of `32767`. Currently I have this which sets any pixel greater than a threshold value of `16384` to zero.

```
array[array > 16384] = 0
```

How can I change this so that the replacement value is the averaged of the X left and right values if the pixel is above the threshold value? If the outlier point is at the very first index or the very last index then the averaged value should just be from the side with values. There could also be multiple values greater than the threshold value (in this example there was only one)

The expected output with the example input that uses 2 adjacent right and left values would be calculated like `(6670 + 7293 + 7264 + 7262)/4 = 7122.25` to get this result

> array = np.array([3147, 3228, 3351, 3789, 4562, 4987, 5688, 6465, 7012, 7560, 
>   7976, 8615, 8698, 8853, 8783, 8949, 9066, 9123, 9172, 9411, 9717, 9696, 
>   9848,10113, 10154, 10227, 10439, 10672, 10287, 10386, 10417,10585, 10607,10461, 
>   10654, 10739, 10634, 10490, 10544, 10645, 10392, 10330, 10044, 9560, 8711, 8152,
>    7506, 7191, 6994, 6601, 6609, 6670, 7293, **7122**, 7264, 7262, 7503 ,7872, 7826, 8037])

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This would work

```
def remove_outlier_pixels(array, adjacent=2):
    outliers = np.argwhere(array > 16384)
    for outlier in outliers:
        outlier = int(outlier)
        left = array[outlier-adjacent:outlier]
        right = array[outlier+1:outlier+adjacent+1]
        array[outlier] = (left.sum() + right.sum())/(left.size + right.size)
    return array
```

Averages out all pixels greater than the threshold with X right and left adjacent values. Also takes care of the corner case if the higher threshold value was at the first or last index

Using this input

> [**99999**  3228  3351  3789  4562  4987  5688  6465  7012  7560  7976  8615
>     8698  8853  8783  8949  9066 **37000**  9172  9411  9717  9696  9848 10113
>    10154 10227 10439 10672 10287 10386 10417 10585 10607 10461 10654 10739
>    10634 10490 10544 10645 10392 10330 10044  9560  8711  8152  7506  7191
>     6994  6601  6609  6670  7293 **32767**  7264  7262  7503  7872  7826 **88888**]

We get

> [ **3289**  3228  3351  3789  4562  4987  5688  6465  7012  7560  7976  8615
>     8698  8853  8783  8949  9066  **9149**  9172  9411  9717  9696  9848 10113
>    10154 10227 10439 10672 10287 10386 10417 10585 10607 10461 10654 10739
>    10634 10490 10544 10645 10392 10330 10044  9560  8711  8152  7506  7191
>     6994  6601  6609  6670  7293  **7122**  7264  7262  7503  7872  7826  **7849**]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
X = 2 #set number of adjacent values
calc_avg = lambda x: (sum([array[x+a]+array[x-a] for a in range(1, X+1)]))/4
array[array > 16384] = [calc_avg(x[0]) for x in np.where(array > 16384)]
```

This may run into issues though if you're cut off value does not have 2 numbers before/after it!